# Error while running openstack code JCloudsNova.java

Tags: jclouds

The description of jclouds is given in the below link.
https://jclouds.apache.org/guides/openstack/. I have packstack installed in the machine.

java -classpath ".:lib/*" JCloudsNova
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.jclouds.apis.ApiMetadata: Provider org.jclouds.openstack.neutron.v2.NeutronApiMetadata could not be instantiated at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232) at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185) at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)  at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404) at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480) at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableCollection$Builder.addAll(ImmutableCollection.java:281)at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableCollection$ArrayBasedBuilder.addAll(ImmutableCollection.java:360)     at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet$Builder.addAll(ImmutableSet.java:508)     at org.jclouds.apis.Apis.all(Apis.java:72)  at org.jclouds.apis.Apis.withId(Apis.java:88)   at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.newBuilder(ContextBuilder.java:169)   at JCloudsNova.(JCloudsNova.java:39)
    at JCloudsNova.main(JCloudsNova.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jclouds/openstack/keystone/v2_0/config/AuthenticationApiModule   at org.jclouds.openstack.neutron.v2.NeutronApiMetadata$Builder.(NeutronApiMetadata.java:78)   at org.jclouds.openstack.neutron.v2.NeutronApiMetadata.(NeutronApiMetadata.java:51)   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)     ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jclouds.openstack.keystone.v2_0.config.AuthenticationApiModule     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 18 more

Comment: Could you share the complete stacktrace?

Comment: Could you please also give a try at https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-examples/tree/master/compute-basics#your-own-openstack-nova ?